# An efficient way to find minimum edge cover using dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

Given an undirected graph with no self loops and parallel edges.

My objective is to find the `minimum edge cover`. I came to know that it can be done efficiently using `bitmask DP`. I have tried a lot but unable to figure out how to define the `state of DP`. Please help in deciding the `DP` state.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't implement using bit-masking, my dynamic programming approach has 2 states -

```
dp[u][hashGuard] // curerntly in u node, this depicts minimum guards required for rest of the nodes encountered later
```

Transition function -

```
// In node u, we have no guards, so we must have to put guards on adjacent nodes
dp[u][0] += dp[v][1] for all adjacent nodes v from u

// In current node u, we have guard. So we can try to minimize the number of guards by puting guards on adjacent nodes or by not putting
dp[u][1] += min(dp[v][1], dp[v][0])  for all adjacent nodes v from u
```

Here is my C++ implementation -

```
// Assuming the graph is a tree. you can transform it for graph by using a visited flag instead of parent array
#define MAX 100001

int dp[MAX << 2][2];
int parent[MAX];
vector <int> adj[MAX];

int minVertexCover(int node, bool hasGuard) {

    if( (int)adj[node].size() == 0 ) return 0;
    if( dp[node][hasGuard] != -1 ) return dp[node][hasGuard];

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)adj[node].size(); i++) {
        int v = adj[node][i];
        if( v != parent[node] ) {
            parent[v] = node;
            if(!hasGuard) {
                sum += minVertexCover(v, true);
            } else {
                sum += min( minVertexCover(v, false), minVertexCover(v, true) );
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[node][hasGuard] = sum + hasGuard;
}

/*
usage:
// graph input
// if node 1 and node 2 connected, then 
// adj[2].push_back(1);
// adj[1].push_back(2)

result = min( minVertexCover(1, false), minVertexCover(1, true) );
if(n > 1) 
    printf("%d\n", result);
else 
    printf("1\n");
*/
```